# How can i save a pdf file in oracle 12c database from j2ee webapp

Tags: java, database, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle12c

I'm developping a J2EE web app, i have to save a pdf file in oracle database (oracle 12c) .

- I need the type of the **attribute** (like varbinary in sqlserver).
- **How to do it** with **java.**

  - Save the pdf to the database .
  - Export it from the database to my webapp.

The file it will be uploaded by user. 
I would like some advices too like if its better to save the pdf in database like binary , something else or just the path. any information or idea will be very interesting for me .

Comment: There's nothing special about PDF files when storing them in a database; do it the same way you'd store any other file. Likewise for reading it back in.

Comment: that's what in my mind but in oracle database i don't know the type of files attributes or binary ones and what is the best way to do i mean the storage way (save files in database or just the path of the file in the files system)

Comment: The type that you are looking for is BLOB. You will find an example in the following link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/StoreBLOBsdataintodatabase.htm

Comment: thank you it's very helpful that's really what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks to Giovanni
**the type is BLOB**.
**How to do it**:

- Example for storing blob data :
  visit http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/StoreBLOBsdataintodatabase.htm .
- Example for reading blob data from database:
   visit http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/ReadBLOBsdatafromdatabase.htm .